# Changing the redirect of the “add to cart” button in woocommerce store in Shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to change the redirect URL in the woocommerce for the 'add to cart' button in pages other than the single product page. The URL for the single product page can be changed with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518938/how-to-change-the-redirect-of-the-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-store). However this solution will not work for the  for any other pages, to change the redirect  after pressing  the  'add to cart' button. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To make **`woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect`** work on pages like shop, categories or tags archives pages, you need first in backend WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display:

[image]
**Disable the checkbox** "Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives".

Then the hooked the code will work with **`woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect`** hook on all woocommerce pages.

```
function wc_add_to_cart_custom_redirect() { 
    // Here the redirection
    return site_url('/mypage/'); 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'wc_add_to_cart_custom_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your **Appearence>Theme Editor>function.php**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    $button_text = __("View product", "woocommerce");
    $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';

    return $button;
}
```

This will change your Add to cart to **View porducts** and the Url would be that specific products's Url