# Is there a way to validade if a field attribute of a product exists in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I found a youtube tutorial to create a plugin in Wordpress to add an input field for each product, so that the client could upload an image. **You can add this field attribute to a product or not**.

The code has a validation function, to check if the image was uploaded or not. If not, promps you a warning saying that you have to. The original code makes the warning active for **all products**, even those that don't have the field.

I changed the code to check if the product has the field or not:

```
// custom input validation
function fp_field_validation($passed, $product_id, $quantity)
{
    $title = $_FILES['fp-file-field'];
    if (empty($_FILES['fp-file-field']["name"]) && isset($title)) {
        // Fails validation
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice(__('Por favor insira una imagen para su producto.', 'fp'), 'error');
    }
    return $passed;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'fp_field_validation', 10, 3);
```

This is the whole code:

```
<?php

// Display the custom text field
function fp_create_field()
{
    $args = array(
        'id' => 'custom_file_field_title',
        'label' => __('Additional Field Title', 'fp'),
        'class' => 'fp-custom-field',
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'description' => __('Enter the title of your additional custom text field.', 'ctwc'),
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input($args);
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'fp_create_field');



// save data from custom field
function fp_save_field_data($post_id)
{
    $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
    $title = isset($_POST['custom_file_field_title']) ? $_POST['custom_file_field_title'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data('custom_file_field_title', sanitize_text_field($title));
    $product->save();
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'fp_save_field_data');


// Display field on the Product Page
function fp_display_field()
{
    global $post;
    // Check for the custom field value
    $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
    $title = $product->get_meta('custom_file_field_title');
    if ($title) {
        // Display the field if not empty
        printf(
            '<div class="fp-custom-field-wrapper"><label for="fp-file-field" style="margin-right: 30px;">%s: </label><input type="file" id="fp-file-field" name="fp-file-field"></div><br /><hr />',
            esc_html($title)
        );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'fp_display_field');


// custom input validation
function fp_field_validation($passed, $product_id, $quantity)
{
    $title = $_FILES['fp-file-field'];
    if (empty($_FILES['fp-file-field']["name"]) && isset($title)) {
        // Fails validation
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice(__('Por favor insira una imagen para su producto.', 'fp'), 'error');
    }
    return $passed;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'fp_field_validation', 10, 3);


// add field data to the cart
function fp_add_field_data_to_cart($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity)
{
    if (!empty($_FILES['fp-file-field']["name"])) {
        // WordPress environment
        require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php');

        $wordpress_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        // $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] is the full server path to wp-content/uploads/2017/05, for multisite works good as well
        // $wordpress_upload_dir['url'] the absolute URL to the same folder, actually we do not need it, just to show the link to file
        $i = 1; // number of tries when the file with the same name already exists

        $file_image = $_FILES['fp-file-field'];
        $new_file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $file_image['name'];
        $new_file_mime = mime_content_type($file_image['tmp_name']);

        if (empty($file_image))
            die('Archivo no seleccionado.');

        if ($file_image['error'])
            die($file_image['error']);

        if ($file_image['size'] > wp_max_upload_size())
            die('Imagen es demasiada grande.');

        if (!in_array($new_file_mime, get_allowed_mime_types()))
            die('Este tipo de archivo no es permitido.');

        while (file_exists($new_file_path)) {
            $i++;
            $new_file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $i . '_' . $file_image['name'];
        }

        // if everything is fine
        if (move_uploaded_file($file_image['tmp_name'], $new_file_path)) {
            $upload_id = wp_insert_attachment(array(
                'guid'           => $new_file_path,
                'post_mime_type' => $new_file_mime,
                'post_title'     => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $file_image['name']),
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_status'    => 'inherit'
            ), $new_file_path);

            // wp_generate_attachment_metadata() won't work if you do not include this file
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

            // Generate and save the attachment metas into the database
            wp_update_attachment_metadata($upload_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata($upload_id, $new_file_path));
        }
        // Add item data
        $cart_item_data['file_field'] = $wordpress_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($new_file_path);
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        $price = $product->get_price();
        $cart_item_data['total_price'] = $price;
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'fp_add_field_data_to_cart', 10, 4);


// update cart price
function fp_calculate_cart_totals($cart_obj)
{
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }
    // Iterate through each cart item
    foreach ($cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($value['total_price'])) {
            $price = $value['total_price'];
            $value['data']->set_price(($price));
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'fp_calculate_cart_totals', 10, 1);


// display field in the cart
function fp_field_to_cart($name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)
{
    if (isset($cart_item['file_field'])) {
        $name .= sprintf(
            '<p>%s</p>',
            esc_html($cart_item['file_field'])
        );
    }
    return $name;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'fp_field_to_cart', 10, 3);


// Add custom field to order object
function fp_add_field_data_to_order($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order)
{
    foreach ($item as $cart_item_key => $values) {
        if (isset($values['file_field'])) {
            $item->add_meta_data(__('Custom Field', 'fp'), $values['file_field'], true);
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'fp_add_field_data_to_order', 10, 4);![![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX7Zs.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yzMh.jpg)
```

I added line 4 and `&& isset($title)` on line 5.

**The problem: **The code works when you go to the individual product page and click to buy it. But in the general page when you click to add to cart, it does work. It let the products with the input field pass.

It should check if the product has the field attribute, if it has prompt a message to add an image, otherwise add the product to the cart, in all pages, not just the individual product page.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that you want to perform validation on a field that not exist on that page (shop page), while this is the case for the single product page. So the validation will always fail on the shop page.. Suppose on the single product page (where the validation works) that I add a product with an image.. but afterwards, I add this product again to the cart (for the same order). 
Is it the intention that a new (extra) image is uploaded for this product? or that only the quantity in the cart should be updated?

Comment: Hi!! No, currently when you add an image on the single product page and clicks to buy, that image is added to the cart as an unique product. If you add the same product, but with different image(or even the same image) again, in the same order, on the cart will show you that product with the different images separetly.


My problem is that I don't know nothing of PHP, and I don't know how to make the validation work on the shop. I supose it should have a code that checks the field attributes and if it has the image input, then validates. But I don't know how to get it.

Comment: What seems to be the easiest solution in this case is that for products that contain an upload field, you adjust the 'add to cart' button (text + link) on the shop page. So that it does not add the product to the cart, but redirect the customer to the single product page, where your validation takes place (because the field is on the single product page). Another (more difficult) solution is to add virtual flags. Like: "the image for this product already been uploaded", flag = true, otherwise false and base your validation on that. These flags can (temporarily) be stored in session variables

Comment: Yeah, I imagine that this solution would be better. Instead of putting in the card, the button leads you to the individual product page, where you can buy it. But I don't know how to change the "add to cart" button to redirect to the individual page product. I looked and found some instruction to change, but product by product, not in a general way. Do you have some article showing how to change 'add to cart' button in all the products?

Comment: I found a solution @7uc1f3r !! Is not what I was looking for, but is a workaround. I found  [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986481/changing-the-redirect-of-the-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-store-in-shop-p) and the code: 
```add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    $button_text = __("View product", "woocommerce");
    $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';

    return $button;
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!! Is not what I was looking for, but is a workaround.
Now instead of adding to the cart, it displays a button that leads you to the individual product page, where the validation works. I found [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986481/changing-the-redirect-of-the-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-store-in-shop-p) and the code:

```js
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );

function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    $button_text = __("View product", "woocommerce");
    $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';

    return $button;
}
```